# Search tips needed?

Tags: discussion, search

Using the SE search tool I searched for 'wavelets', and got one set of questions, then I searched for 'wavelet' and got an overlapping set. Then I searched for 'wavelet*' and got another set. I didn't realise that searching was precise enough to distinguish between singulars and plurals, or that you could try an asterisk wild-card. Where can I find this information, say beginner-level ninja search tips, rather than the super ninja search tips (which I've seen)?

Comment: do an empty search for search tips... The general search behaviour is described before the super ninja options

Comment: No mention of singular/plural matching or wildcard matching (if that's available outside url fields), though...? Oh, well.

Comment: At the very beginning, it says: ***apples oranges**

… will return any questions or answers containing "apples" or "oranges"*. Note the quotes, so it's an exact string match. I know, it's a bit annoying. Also, if your word happens to be a top 10 tag, it will automatically search for the tag and not the word. For the longest time, I couldn't find [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096) with the search "compilable functions", despite it being in the title. It was because it didn't have the [tag:functions] tag (which is a top 10 tag). I fixed it by adding the tag to the Q.

Answer (score 4):

Do an [empty search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=#), and there will be a link **Advanced Search Tips** that opens in-place (hence the lack of link here). I've copied the content of that help below. More help on advanced search in the Help Center's [search-specific section](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

```
tags      [tag]
exact     "words here"
author    user:1234
          user:me (yours)
score     score:3 (3+)
          score:0 (none)
answers   answers:3 (3+)
          answers:0 (none)
          isaccepted:yes
          hasaccepted:no
          inquestion:1234
views     views:250
sections  title:apples
          body:"apples oranges"
url       url:"*.example.com"
favorites infavorites:mine
          infavorites:1234
status    closed:yes
          duplicate:no
          migrated:no
          wiki:no
          deleted:no
types     is:question
          is:answer
exclude   -[tag]
          -apples
```

### Examples

Search for unanswered questions that are not closed and has exactly one answer, i.e. has a single, unaccepted answer (from [this post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/907/89)):

```
isanswered:no closed:no hasaccepted:no answers:1
```

Comment: I rage-answered because I couldn't find the relevant help page for 5 minutes.