# How to find unanswered questions that really have answers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered, search

Currently there are [368 unanswered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) questions, and [352 that have zero answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers).

This means that there are 16 that have at least one answer, but for which the answer has a non-positive vote count.  How can I find them?

Comment: Where did you get the number 368 from? I get 3201unanswered questions when I follow your link.

Comment: @m_goldberg This question was asked in January 2013... almost 3 years ago! :)

Comment: @R.M. Ah, I failed to notice that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following search query should give you all questions that are categorized as unanswered, but have at least one answer with non-positive vote count:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ano+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1

Answer (score 12):

You can't do that with the tabs on that page or using the search, but you can find them using the API:

```
unanswered = Last@Reap@Block[{i = 1, more},
      While[{more = "has_more" /. #, Sow["items" /. #]} &@
        Import["http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/unanswered?pagesize=100&site=mathematica&filter=!BGS1(RNaQDJUqhjM_kktL.ISG39ejq&page=" <> ToString@i++, "JSON"]; 
        more =!= False
       ]
      ]~Flatten~2;

Cases[unanswered, 
 {"answer_count" -> Except[0], "link" -> l_, ___, "title" -> t_} :> Hyperlink[t, l]] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: P.S. The `filter=...` in the URL is an [API filter](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) that I created to return only the necessary fields. In essence, this moves the filtering operation from mma to the API service, which makes for cleaner code. The filter is non-expiring and immutable, so this answer will always work.